# Show that $(0,1)$ is uncountable if and only if $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am trying to write a proof for this problem, and have been having difficulty completing the other direction of the iff statement. Below is what I have.

> ($\Rightarrow$) Let $(0,1)$ be uncountable. Assume towards a contradiction that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable. Any subset of a countable set is also a countable set.  We know that because $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, $(0,1)$ must be countable. However, this contradicts our claim that $(0,1)$ is uncountable. Therefore, in order for $(0,1)$ to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}$ must be uncountable. This contradicts our original assumption that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable.
>
> ($\Leftarrow$) Let $0.d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}...d_{k}...$ denote the decimal
> representation of a number in $(0,1)$. Assume towards a contradiction
> that $(0,1)$ is countable. This means that there exists a function $f$
> such that $f: \mathbb{N} \to (0,1)$ that is one-to-one and onto. For each $m
> > \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(m)$ is a real number between 0 and 1. We represent this as
> $$0.d_{m1}d_{m2}d_{m3}...d_{mn}$$
>
> This means that for each $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ $d_{mn}$ is the digit from the
> set $\{0,1,2,...,9\}$ that represents the $n$th digit in the decimal
> expansion of $f(m)$. The key assumption about this one-to-one
> correspondence is that every real number in (0,1) is assumed to appear
> somewhere on the list.
>
> Define a real number $x \in (0,1)$ with the decimal expansion $x =
> > 0.b_{1}b_{2}b_{3}b_{4}...$ using the rule $$b_{n}= \begin{cases} 
>        2 & \text{if}\ d_{nn} \neq 2\\
>        3 & \text{if}\ d_{nn} =2. 
>          \end{cases}$$

There are other similar posts (such as [this post from 2016](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849193/show-that-0-1-is-uncountable-if-and-only-if-mathbbr-is-uncountable) and [this post from 2017](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121350/proving-that-the-interval-0-1-is-uncountable)), but they have not been helpful to me. I am looking for guidance regarding my specific proof about what can be improved/changed, and perhaps a hint to guide me in the right direction so that I may complete the other direction of the proof. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's wrong with using the bijection $x \mapsto \arctan x$ after suitable scaling?

Comment: I think this works.  You should note that some numbers (those with terminating decimal expansions) have two different decimal representations, and should express some sort of argument why that's not a problem for your proof.  (It's not a problem, but you should explain why it's not.)

Comment: ...or $$\log\left(\frac1x-1\right)$$ is a bijection between $\;(0,1)\;$ and $\;\Bbb R\;$ ...

Comment: Another bijection: $x \to (1+\frac x {1+|x|})/2$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789029/homeomorphism-from-0-1-to-mathbbr

Comment: @JoseAvilez There is nothing wrong with using this, I am just not sure how to incorporate that into what I have written so far. It did not come to me as intuitively as the rest of the proof.